# How do I stop Visual Studio 2015 from openning javascript files with the HTML editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a project with some javascript files. Every time I open a js file Visual Studio opens it with the HTML editor.

I already tried to map the ".js" extension to the JavaScript Editor and set the file to open with the JavaScript Editor by default. It doesn't matter, VS appears to ignore the preferences.